# What variant are these hash strings?

Tags: hash

I came across these hashes while working on an online lab:

1. cijmqceuepl060ovqn00
2. cij9n63u5mrpmcfkv2g0
3. cij9mnf985671v797ed0
4. cij9m06p0prapsjdacl0
5. cij9ioju5mrpmcfkrfrg

I reckon these are time-based hashes, which takes the current timestamp into account while hashing some raw values, since these records are persisted at relatively close timestamps. Though, searches with the keyword 'time-based hashes' show no matches.

Could anyone name the variant of the hashes above?

Comment: It's impossible to say. Those hashes could be base64 encoded or base36 encoded. Or something else entirely. And they're not necessarily time-based hashes. Perhaps "cijX" is the encoding for the first 3 bytes (in base 64) of the key field, which is a "product category" field in a database, and you're looking at hashes for a list of products, all from the same category. Without more context about where you got the data, there's no way to even guess what those numbers represent.